# Restoring AutoFilter with xlFilterValues raises error 13 Type mismatch if Len(Criteria1(i))>255?

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I've inherited some VBA code that attempts to [save and restore filters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9489126/1026) in Excel 2010-2016 (I'm testing on Excel 2016 - 32bit, 16.0.4549.1000). I've already learned this is [pretty much impossible to do properly](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b3b63a43-39b8-4109-973d-121c17b750d4/vba-autofilter-state-excel-2010?forum=excel) and in a sane way (e.g. [Get Date Autofilter in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32040238/get-date-autofilter-in-excel-vba/32062115#32062115)), but the number of different ways it can fail amazes me.

In particular, it seems that **an `xlFilterValues` filter, which selects cells with value longer than 254 characters, can not be saved and restored**:

- the values in `.Criteria1(i)` are truncated to 256 chars when reading,
- if you save the criteria array (`saved = .Criteria1`) and attempt to restore it later via `.AutoFilter Criteria1:=saved ...`, the `.AutoFilter` will report "Run-time error '13'       Type Mismatch" if any Len(saved(i)) >= 256

The testcase, which can be run in an empty workbook is listed below.

Can everyone reproduce? Any thoughts on an easy way around this limitation?

```
Sub test()
    Const CRITERIA_LEN = 257 ' 255 or less works, 256 throws error


    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim filtRng As Range: Set filtRng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(5, 1))
    Dim s100 As String: s100 = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
    Const PREFIX_LEN = 2 ' the length of the "=X" prefix in Criteria1(i)
    Dim longStr As String: longStr = Mid(s100 & s100 & s100, 1, CRITERIA_LEN - PREFIX_LEN)

    ws.Cells(1, 1).Value2 = "header"
    ws.Cells(2, 1).Value2 = "A" & longStr
    ws.Cells(3, 1).Value2 = "B" & longStr
    ws.Cells(4, 1).Value2 = "C" & longStr
    ws.Cells(5, 1).Value2 = "another value"
    If Not ws.AutoFilterMode Then
        filtRng.AutoFilter
    End If




    SET_BREAKPOINT_HERE = 1
    ' after hitting the breakpoint use the autofilter to select the three long values by typing '123' into the autofilter search




    Dim fs As Filters: Set fs = ws.AutoFilter.Filters
    If Not fs.Item(1).On Then Exit Sub
    Debug.Print "Operator = " & fs.Item(1).Operator ' should be xlFilterValues (7)
    Debug.Print "Len(.Criteria1(1)) = " & Len(fs.Item(1).Criteria1(1)) ' this is never larger than 256
    Debug.Print "Len(.Criteria1(2)) = " & Len(fs.Item(1).Criteria1(2))
    Debug.Print "Len(.Criteria1(3)) = " & Len(fs.Item(1).Criteria1(3))

    ' Save the filter
    Dim crit As Variant
    crit = fs.Item(1).Criteria1
    'crit = Array("=A" & longStr, "=B" & longStr, "=C" & longStr)   ' This line has the same effect

    ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData ' reset the filter

    ' Try to restore
    filtRng.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=crit, _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues
    ' => Run-time error '13'       Type Mismatch
End Sub
```

Comment: **Fun fact:** I'm using Excel 2016 (Desktop). After running the macro (no changes), no error. However, the filter filtered out everything -- not just the original filtered row -- so there was no longer any visible data.

Comment: @Mistella, thanks for taking a look! Just to confirm, was the Operator=7, Len(Criteria1(1/2/3))=256 in the debug output?

Comment: Yes. It was. What I found interesting was the difference in result, since (if I understood you correctly) you got a run-time error and the macro never completed. While for me, the macro completed, and filtered, but since the criteria didn't match any of the "data", none of those rows were visible.

Comment: @Mistella, right. So we both see the criteria being truncated on read (making it unpleasant to work around), but attempting to filter on a long string behaves differently for us. I just found my version of Excel is almost a year old, I'll update the question if I get different results with a different version. Thanks again!

Comment: Excel 2016 (Desktop) Code ran and filtered results were 3* strings of len 256 & 1* "another value" . Had to comment out  SET_BREAKPOINT_HERE = 1   so don't know if I missed something.

Comment: @QHarr, yes, the whole point is to break on that line and set up the problematic filter manually.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue today also. Really unfortunate that this has this limitation. I think the best thing we can hope to do is the following.

```
Function MakeValid(ByVal sSearchTerm as string) as string
  if len(sSearchTerm) > 255 then
    MakeValid = Left(sSearchTerm,254) & "*"
  else
    MakeValid = sSearchTerm
  end if
End Function
Sub Test()
  ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= MakeValid(sSearchTerm), Operator:=Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Ultimately, the way it works, is it bypasses the problem by using a pattern search (so matches the first 253 characters, and then it searches for any pattern from there). This won't always work, in fact it is bound to not work at some points, but it seems this is the best option we have (other than designing our systems around this issue)

Seems like this also works for arrays:

```
Function MakeValid(ByVal sSearchTerm as string) as string
  if len(sSearchTerm) > 255 then
    MakeValid = Left(sSearchTerm,254) & "*"
  else
    MakeValid = sSearchTerm
  end if
End Function
Sub Test()
  Dim i as long
  for i = lbound(sSearchTerms) to ubound(sSearchTerms)
    sSearchTerms(i) = MakeValid(sSearchTerms(i))
  next

  ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= sSearchTerms, Operator:=Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

It's kinda a bad solution but it sort of works

Comment: For me the trailing asterisk has special meaning only when `Criteria1` is a string or an array with length <= 2. Doing `Criteria1:=Array("=foo*", "=bar*", "=baz*")` does not select "foo123" for me...

Comment: @Nickolay thanks for raising this issue. I'll check on my end, as I was also concerned that might be the case but didn't totally test it.

Comment: @Nickolay I didn't manage to fix it unfortunately. The only thing I can suggest is to ensure your table has IDs, save the filtered IDs and restore the filtered IDs... Not a good solution but at least it works...