# How to set value of hidden/filtered cells in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I've got rows 3 and 4 filtered out. I'm trying set cells value at once:

```
range("A2:A5").value = 5
```

and it only sets value to A2 and A5. Of course I can set cells value one by one, but it's painfully slow.

How can I do that fast and correct?

Funny fact: `range("A3:A4").value = 5` works. Is that a bug or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It doesn't need a loop through all the cells in the range and fills all the filtered cells, hidden and visible.

```
Sub test()
Range("A2:A5").FormulaArray = "5"    
End Sub
```

Comment: oh I've tried with .Formula already, but not formulaarray. That's helpfull, but still not perfect because formulaarray has length limit and probably more problems.

Comment: Hi @ingwarus Yes. That's a good point. [Range.FormulaArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.FormulaArray) has limit of 255 characters. Also, it may not be the first choice to be used to fill a real formula(starting with =) over a large range. It is only useful when an absolute value like "5" or "ABC" needs to be entered without loop like in this case. To encounter the character limit of 255 through VBA, it must be a long string(data type).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps starting the macro with unhiding the columns end ending the macro with hiding them again. Shoud the solution of Victor not work, let me know and I will write the code for it.

Edit for the code;

```
Sub Filter()

'Remove existing filter in colmn "2"
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabel1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2

'Change row A to value 5
Range("A2:A6").Value = "5"

'Re-activate filter
    'Filter in column 2
    'Only show values stating "Yes"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabel1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="yes"

End Sub
```

This works on my table. The able has three columns, named "1", "2" and "3". Column 2 contains either "Yes" or "No" at random (for easy filtering proof).

If I filter on Yes and activate the macro, everything in column A ("1") is now value "5", including hidden rows.

Comment: If you know simple way to reenable fiters again that would be solution

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the code. If it works, please mark it as the answer, if it does not work, let me know and I will see what's wrong!

Comment: Please remember that I've presented simplified problem. I know how to filter word "yes". I don't know how to revert all original filters combination. Possibly many filter types on many columns, made by user, so i don,t know them.

Comment: Then I have misunderstood your question, my apologies. I have seached for ways to import set autofilter settings, but have not been able to find one. I'm glad to see another answer has solved your problem!

Comment: Note that the "save and restore the autofilter" route is rather frustrating, as there are criteria that can't be read from the autofilter programmatically or fail during the restore attempt. Some links I collected while researching this are in [my question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49633705/1026).